# Child Component has many parents and parents want to access its method. How I can achieve that?

Tags: reactjs

I have several filters and they are used by two parents. Both parents have apply button and I want when it is clicked validation function inside each filter to be called. How I can do that?

```
function DateFilter() {
  const [isError, setError] = useState(false);
  function validation() {
    // if not valid show error message and apply button disabled
    setError(true);
  }

  return ...
}
```

```
<DesktopDialog onApply={sendBackend}> <-- apply button is there
  <DateFilter onChange={setForm}>
</DesktopDialog>
```

and

```
<MobileFilterModal onApply={sendBackend}> <-- apply button is there
  <DateFilter onChange={(v) => setForm('date', v)}>
  ...other filters
</MobileFilterModal>
```

I heard we can use useImperativeHandle but are there alternative options I can use?

Answer (score 1):

You have to rethink your component structure. What you're trying to achieve is anti-pattern in React as the data can flow only one way.

The validation should happen in your parent component and `DateFilter` should probably just receive the result of it. You can extract this common functionality into a hook for example.

There might be multiple ways to do this, it all really depends on your application and its architecture.

Answer (score 1):

If you told about a lot of parents. Right way will be [lifted state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). For instance you can use [context api](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

A usage example similar to your case:
https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-context-and-usecontext/

Comment: Context is kind of overkill OP is trying to solve in my opinion (from the examples it doesn't look like the components are nested in large trees).